# Nested XML Parsing using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<Tax>
  <TaxCategory>
    <TaxCategoryType>Single</TaxCategoryType>

    <TaxRates>
      <Rate>
        <From>0</From>
        <To>8500</To>
        <Multiply>0</Multiply>
        <Subtract>0</Subtract>
      </Rate>

      <Rate>
        <From>8501</From>
        <To>14500</To>
        <Multiply>0.15</Multiply>
        <Subtract>1275</Subtract>
      </Rate>

      <Rate>
        <From>14501</From>
        <To>19500</To>
        <Multiply>0.25</Multiply>
        <Subtract>2725</Subtract>
      </Rate>

      <Rate>
        <From>19501</From>
        <To>60000</To>
        <Multiply>0.29</Multiply>
        <Subtract>3505</Subtract>
      </Rate>

      <Rate>
        <From>60001</From>
        <Multiply>0.35</Multiply>
        <Subtract>7105</Subtract>
      </Rate>
    </TaxRates>
  </TaxCategory>

  <TaxCategory>
    <TaxCategoryType>Married</TaxCategoryType>

    <TaxRates>
      <Rate>
        <From>0</From>
        <To>11900</To>
        <Multiply>0</Multiply>
        <Subtract>0</Subtract>
      </Rate>

      <Rate>
        <From>11901</From>
        <To>21200</To>
        <Multiply>0.15</Multiply>
        <Subtract>1785</Subtract>
      </Rate>

      <Rate>
        <From>21201</From>
        <To>28700</To>
        <Multiply>0.25</Multiply>
        <Subtract>3905</Subtract>
      </Rate>

      <Rate>
        <From>28701</From>
        <To>60000</To>
        <Multiply>0.29</Multiply>
        <Subtract>5053</Subtract>
      </Rate>

      <Rate>
        <From>60001</From>
        <Multiply>0.35</Multiply>
        <Subtract>8653</Subtract>
      </Rate>
    </TaxRates>
  </TaxCategory>

  <TaxCategory>
    <TaxCategoryType>Parent</TaxCategoryType>

    <TaxRates>
      <Rate>
        <From>0</From>
        <To>9800</To>
        <Multiply>0</Multiply>
        <Subtract>0</Subtract>
      </Rate>

      <Rate>
        <From>9801</From>
        <To>15800</To>
        <Multiply>0.15</Multiply>
        <Subtract>1470</Subtract>
      </Rate>

      <Rate>
        <From>15801</From>
        <To>21200</To>
        <Multiply>0.25</Multiply>
        <Subtract>3050</Subtract>
      </Rate>

      <Rate>
        <From>21201</From>
        <To>60000</To>
        <Multiply>0.29</Multiply>
        <Subtract>3898</Subtract>
      </Rate>

      <Rate>
        <From>60001</From>
        <Multiply>0.35</Multiply>
        <Subtract>7498</Subtract>
      </Rate>
    </TaxRates>
  </TaxCategory>
</Tax>
```

Now, I want to extract the `Multiply` and `Subtract` values for the tax with category type single `TaxCategoryType` and the tax rate with `from == 0` and `to == 8500`.

**How can I do this with LINQ?**

This is what I have done so far:

```
var taxCategory = from tc in xmlDoc.Descendants("TaxCategory")
    where tc.Element("TaxCategoryType").Value == "Single"
    //and TaxRate.From = 0 && TaxRate.To = 8500
    select tc;
```

What should I put instead of the comment since the `From` and `To` tags are deeply nested within the `TaxCategory` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like the following:

```
var taxCategory = xmlDoc.Descendants("TaxCategory")
    .First(tc => tc.Element("TaxCategoryType").Value == "Single")
    .Descendants("Rate")
    .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Element("From").Value == "0" 
        && r.Element("To").Value == "8500");
```

**UPDATE:**
This is what I came up using query syntax (and only one query):

```
var category = (from r in xmlDoc.Descendants("TaxCategory").Descendants("Rate")
        where r.Parent.Parent.Element("TaxCategoryType").Value == "Single"
           && r.Element("From").Value == "0" && r.Element("To").Value == "8500"
        select r).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks ChrFin :)  Do you know how to rewrite it in query syntax as well please?  I would be very grateful.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you so much ChrFin :)  I appreciate it immensely :)

Comment: @Matthew: Please see my update - maybe someone knows a better way, as I think this could be slow for big XML files...

Comment: Thank you so much ChrFin.  I learned a lot from your answer :)